# Picturebox inside a group box doesn't display image

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

I have an array of 20 images, and 20 picturebox, I tried displaying those images in the pictureboxes and this code made it worked:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= ExtractedBoxes.Count(); x++)
{
    ((PictureBox)this.Controls["pictureBox" + x.ToString()]).Image = ExtractedBoxes[x - 1];
}
```

But when I placed all my picture box inside a groupbox or a tablelayoutpanel it doesn't show. I want them inside a groupbox or a tablelayoutpanel so it they will be organized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then access your `Control Collection` of your *Actual Container*.If it is `GroupBox` use:

```
groupBoxname.Controls
```

Instead of `this.Controls`.If your container is `TableLayoutPanel` then use `tableLayoutPanelname.Controls` and so on.